# TypeError computing gradients with GradientTape.gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, recurrent-neural-network, hessian

Hello,

I'm currently trying to compute gradients in **Tensorflow 1.13.1** and using the `GradientTape` class as explained in the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) , but I am getting a `TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>`.
Below, I will include two simple cases where I get this error, using only out-of-the-box Tensorflow function, the first one being the simpler minimal working example, and the second one that I actually need to solve/get a work-around. For completeness, I am using **Python 3.6.8**.

### Simpler one

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.constant([1., 2., 3.])
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as gg:
    gg.watch(x)
    f1 = tf.map_fn(lambda a: a**2, x)
    f2 = x*x

# Computes gradients
d_fx1 = gg.gradient(f1, x)     #Line that causes the error
d_fx2 = gg.gradient(f2, x)     #No error
del gg #delete persistent GradientTape

with tf.Session() as sess:
    d1, d2 = sess.run((d_fx1, d_fx2))
print(d1, d2)
```

In this code, `f1` and `f2` are computed in different ways, but give the same array. However, when trying to compute the gradients associated with them, the first line one gives the following error, whereas the second line works flawlessly. I report below the stack trace of the error

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9c59a2cf2d9b> in <module>()
     15 
     16 with tf.Session() as sess:
---> 17     d1, d2 = sess.run((d_fx1, d_fx2))
     18 print(d1, d2)

C:\HOMEWARE\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\envs\rdwsenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    927     try:
    928       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 929                          run_metadata_ptr)
    930       if run_metadata:
    931         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\HOMEWARE\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\envs\rdwsenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1135     # Create a fetch handler to take care of the structure of fetches.
   1136     fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(
-> 1137         self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
   1138 
   1139     # Run request and get response.

C:\HOMEWARE\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\envs\rdwsenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, graph, fetches, feeds, feed_handles)
    469     """
    470     with graph.as_default():
--> 471       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
    472     self._fetches = []
    473     self._targets = []

C:\HOMEWARE\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\envs\rdwsenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
    259     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
    260       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.
--> 261       return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
    262     elif isinstance(fetch, collections.Mapping):
    263       return _DictFetchMapper(fetch)

C:\HOMEWARE\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\envs\rdwsenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, fetches)
    368     """
    369     self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
--> 370     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
    371     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
    372 

C:\HOMEWARE\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\envs\rdwsenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    368     """
    369     self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
--> 370     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
    371     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
    372 

C:\HOMEWARE\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\envs\rdwsenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
    256     if fetch is None:
    257       raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r' % (fetch,
--> 258                                                                  type(fetch)))
    259     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
    260       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.

TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Please note that I also tried computing only one gradient at a time, i.e with `persistent=False`, and got the same results.

### Actual need

Below, I will include also the minimal working example to reproduce the same error I got, but trying to resolve the problem I am actually working on.

In this code, I'm using a `RNN` to compute an output w.r.t some inputs, and I need to compute the `jacobian` of this output w.r.t the inputs.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import RNN, GRUCell

# Define size of variable. TODO: adapt to data
inp_dim = 2
num_units = 50
batch_size = 100
timesteps = 10

# Reset the graph, so as to avoid errors
tf.reset_default_graph()

# Building the model
inputs = tf.ones(shape=(timesteps, batch_size, inp_dim))

# Follow gradient computations
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(inputs)
    cells = [GRUCell(num_units), GRUCell(num_units)]
    rnn = RNN(cells, time_major=True, return_sequences=True)
    f = rnn(inputs)
d_fx = g.batch_jacobian(f, inputs)

# Run graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    grads = sess.run(d_fx)
grads.shape
```

Regarding the stack trace, I get the same error but with less lines (there are one `for_fetch`, `<listcomp>` and `__init` less in this stack trace). For completeness, I still include it below

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-bb2ce4eebe87> in <module>()
     25 with tf.Session() as sess:
     26     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
---> 27     grads = sess.run(d_fx)
     28 grads.shape

C:\HOMEWARE\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\envs\rdwsenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    927     try:
    928       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 929                          run_metadata_ptr)
    930       if run_metadata:
    931         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\HOMEWARE\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\envs\rdwsenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1135     # Create a fetch handler to take care of the structure of fetches.
   1136     fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(
-> 1137         self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
   1138 
   1139     # Run request and get response.

C:\HOMEWARE\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\envs\rdwsenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, graph, fetches, feeds, feed_handles)
    469     """
    470     with graph.as_default():
--> 471       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
    472     self._fetches = []
    473     self._targets = []

C:\HOMEWARE\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\envs\rdwsenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
    256     if fetch is None:
    257       raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r' % (fetch,
--> 258                                                                  type(fetch)))
    259     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
    260       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.

TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

I feel like there is a bug with some Tensorflow function that gets me the error, however I am not sure. At the end, what interest me is getting a `tensor` containing the **jacobian** of the output of my network w.r.t to the inputs. How can I achieve that using other tools, or correcting my code ?

**EDIT**: Ok, so I took into account the comments by danyfang, and tried to look into the issue raised on Github he quoted about `tf.gradients` returning `None` instead of `0` due to some implementation design in low-level Tensorflow.

Therefore, I tried to create a simple case where I am sure that gradient are different from `0`, by computing `tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x), x)`. I am posting below a MWE.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.]])
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as gg:
    gg.watch(x)
    y = tf.matmul(x, tf.transpose(x))
    f1 = tf.map_fn(lambda a: a, y)

# Computes gradients
d_fx1 = gg.gradient(f1, x)
d_yx = gg.gradient(y, x)
del gg #delete persistent GradientTape

with tf.Session() as sess:
    #d1 = sess.run(d_fx1) # Same error None type
    d2 = sess.run(d_yx) #Works flawlessly. returns array([[2., 4., 6.]], dtype=float32)
d2
```

This shows (at least in my opinion) that the error arises not because of the behavior reported by this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3972), but another thing due to lower level implementation.

Comment: I just read something here. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3972

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked into the link you commented, and edited my post. While the end error is the same, it seems that my problem is not due to some ``0/None`` gradients.

Comment: I agree. But I think the problem is really because of `tf.map_fn` being functional, `tf.map_fn` maps functions to tensors but itself does not perform operations on those tensors. If being really specific, the gradient is actually the function (that is mappped) with respect to input tensors but not `tf.map_fn` with respect to input tensors. I looked into the tensorflow graph of the two approches in example 1 and they are in fact very different.

Comment: Here is another reasoning, function `tf.map_fn` can be replaced by a while loop, isn't it? So as if you are calculating the gradient of a while loop with respect to input tenosr `x`.

Comment: Oh ok, now I get the difference of behavior. I'm going to ask about a feature request on Github, and talk about that with the devs. I'm going to try to get a work around, and if I succeed I'll post my solution

Comment: Glad to hear that, i would be looking forward to the conversation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Below, I report how I computed the `tf.hessians` of my output w.r.t the inputs.

I succeeded in computing the gradients using the function `tf.gradients`. However, according to the documentation this function uses *symbolic derivation* whereas `GradientTape.gradient` uses *automatic differentiation*. In the papers I am reading, they talk about *automatic differentiation*, so I don't know if I'll encounter some problems later on, but at least my code runs.

Below, I post a MWE with the RNN code I already used.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import RNN, GRUCell, Dense

# Define size of variable. TODO: adapt to data
inp_dim = 2
num_units = 50
batch_size = 100
timesteps = 10

# Reset the graph, so as to avoid errors
tf.reset_default_graph()

inputs = tf.ones(shape=(timesteps, batch_size, inp_dim))

### Building the model
cells = [GRUCell(num_units), GRUCell(num_units)]
rnn = RNN(cells, time_major=True, return_sequences=True)
final_layer = Dense(1, input_shape=(num_units,))

# Apply to inputs
last_state = rnn(inputs)
f = final_layer(last_state)

[derivs] = tf.gradients(f, inputs)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    grads = sess.run(derivs)
```

Just to warn any interested bystander that would like to compute **second order derivatives**, using `tf.gradients(tf.gradients(func, vars))` is not supported. There is a function called `tf.hessian` too, but replacing `tf.gradients` by `tf.hessian` in the code above did not work, and led to an error so long that I will not include it here. I will most likely do an **issue** on Github, that I will link here for anyone interested. For the moment, as I encountered a unsatisfying workaround, I will mark my own response as solving my problem.

## Computing second-order derivatives

See this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28310) on Github.